# C# Checking if there is same random value in the array or not

Tags: c#, arrays, random

I want to check if there is same value in the array or not as I mentioned in the title. And if there is, I want to pass that value and check another random value to add to listbox.

In my form, there is 2 textBox, 1 listbox and 1 button. When button is clicked, listbox has to show random numbers up to sum of textbox1 and textbox2. For instance;

5 entered from textbox1 and 10 entered from textbox2. Sum is of course 15 and listbox has to show 15 random numbers but those numbers have to be different from each other.

I wrote something like that and used Contains method to check if there is same value or not. But the program froze and didn't give any error.

```
    int a, b;
    Random rnd = new Random();
    int[] array;

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        a = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
        b = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);
        int c = a + b;
        array = new int[c];

        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            int number = rnd.Next(c);

            foreach(int numbers in array)
            {
                if (array.Contains(numbers))
                {
                    i--;
                }

                else
                {
                    array[i] = number;
                    listBox1.Items.Add(array[i]);
                }
            }              
        }
```

I also did it without foreach(Only Contains part I mean). Also didn't work. I wrote in "else";

```
 array[i] += number;
```

it also didn't work.

I would be very appreciated if you help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use `do...while` instead of `for loop`

`Random.Next` get the value from `0` to `c - 1`, so `rnd.Next(c + 1);` need to add `1` otherwise, the loop will not be stopped.

```
var array = new int[c];
int number;  

for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
{
    do
    {
        number = rnd.Next(c + 1);

    } while (array.Contains(number));
    array[i] = number;
    listBox1.Items.Add(array[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

instead of a for loop, use a while loop:

```
int = 0;
while(i<c)
{
    int random rnd.Next(c);
    if(!array.Contains(random))
         array[i++] = random;
}
```

you may also create a list of numbers from 1-15 and then shuffle them (as your random function will create only random numbers from 1-15 just random):

```
array = Enumberable.Range(0,c).OrderBy(x => rnd.Next()).ToArray();
```

The above code is much faster, because imagine that we have generated 14 random numbers and only one number (5 for instance) left, it has to go through loop several times so that finally random number that is generated equals to 5, but in the above code there is no need to check that, we just have all numbers and then we shuffle it.

Answer (score 1):

You basically need to shuffle your data. Create a collection with all values:

```
var temp = Enumerable.Range(0, c);
```

Now order it by random

```
temp = temp.OrderBy(_ => rnd.Next());
```

Now you can add `temp` to your `listBox`

Or, as single line:

```
listBox1.Items.AddRange(Enumerable.Range(0, c).OrderBy(_ => rnd.Next()));
```

Comment: Note that `OrderBy` is `O(n log n)`, shuffling a list can be done in `O(n)`.

Comment: @Caramiriel yes, you are right. [Fisher–Yates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) algorithm require `O(n)` operations. But when we deal with small collections `OrderBy` works fine